# Get dynamic state radiobutton in function

Tags: javascript

I am learning js, and I have a question that has confused me a little, I made a wrapper for the radiobutton, it is displayed in a modal window, and I want to transfer the value of the variable radiobutton to another function, tried it through `var radioValue = $("input[name='radio']:checked").val();`, but it retains the value that was when the page was loaded

```
$('input:radio[name=radio]').on('change', function () {
    radioValue = $("input[name='radio']:checked").val();
});


(function(w,d,u,b){w['Bitrix24FormObject']=b;w[b] = w[b] || function(){arguments[0].ref=u;
    (w[b].forms=w[b].forms||[]).push(arguments[0])};
    if(w[b]['forms']) return;
    var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=1;s.src=u+'?'+(1*new Date());
    var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
})(window,document,'https://bistropechat.bitrix24.ru/bitrix/js/crm/form_loader.js','b24form');


b24form({"id":"5","lang":"ru","sec":"uwp5dl","type":"button","click":"", "presets": {"my_cookie1": "ValueChecked: " + radioValue }});
```

Comment: you're trying to pass the updated radioValue to which function? `b24form` ?

do you call b24form in this exact sequential way in your code? 

if so radioValue will have no value, since this value is only set on the on change event. i.e. b24form is called before a change event can be registered.

Comment: OK, I understood that, and in what way can I transmit the changed state?